# How can I find and remove missing airdropped files from iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, airdrop

I airdropped two files separately from MacOs Catalina to iOS 13.1.2 on iPhone 7.
The files were

> Install macOS Catalina.app

and

> Install macOS Catalina.app.zip

Each one more than 8 GB. after sending files the options list of apps didn't appear on the iPhone and files were missing.

But when I checked the storage part of setting app it appeared that around 16GB files are on my device and they are occupying the iPhones's space.

How can I find and remove missing airdropped files?

Comment: Where did you expect the files to be stored?

Comment: @IconDaemon In a app called iZip Pro or files!